# rewriting an extra query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope to learn how to do regular expressions one day but for now I need a little help.

I have this set up in my .htaccess. So that a query to example.doc is internally forwarded to download.php?file=example.doc

```
RewriteRule ^(download.php.*) - [L]         
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(doc|docx))$ download.php?file=$1
```

I need it changed slightly so that an extra query sting (always present) on the document is also internally rewritten and passed to the php. For example: a query to example.doc?verify=whatever would be internally rewritten to download.php?file=example.doc&verify=whatever

Thanks!
Neddy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I preserve the existing query string in a mod_rewrite rule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1525301/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QSA] flag should take care of this (Query String Append).