# Maintaining the query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've correctly configured my website to re-route every piece of traffic from

mywonderfulwebsite.com/**folder1**/*whatever-url*.php

to

http://**folder1**.mywonderfulwebsite.com/*whatever-url-as-above*.php

Question is: many times, an external website links the page with GET parameters, for example

mywonderfulwebsite.com/folder1/whatever-url.php**?trackingToken=1**

So, question is how to make the mod_rewrite pass in the GET parameters to the "rewrited" url, like this:

folder1.mywonderfulwebsite.com/whatever-url-as-above.php**?trackingToken=1**

Currently, I'm doing the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName mywonderfulwebsite.com
   ServerAlias www.mywonderfulwebsite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mywonderfulwebsite/
   DirectoryIndex index.html

   <Directory />
      allow from all
      Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
   </Directory>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^/folder1/(.*)?$    http://folder1.mywonderfulwebsite.com/$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

**This piece of htaccess is awful: for example, trying to access this url:**

www.mywonderfulwebsite.com/folder1/**atextfile.txt**

Redirects to

folder1.mywonderfulwebsite.com/**atextfile.txt&**

In fact, the mod_rewrite appends the trailing &

How do I fix this issue? **How to correctly redirecting to the correct ( also with GET parameters ) url?**

Many thanks

Comment: The part from the question mark on is called the **query string**, **GET** is the HTTP method.

Comment: You're right, too much of $_GET in php :) thank you for the precisation

Comment: possible duplicate of [rewriting an extra query string with mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713760/rewriting-an-extra-query-string-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: ... [How do I preserve the existing query string in a mod_rewrite rule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1525301/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the [QSA] flag to your other flags to have the [Q]uery [S]tring [A]ppended automatically.

```
[L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: I've forgotten to ask you also one thing:
Currently, I'm also trying to redirect traffic from domain.com to www.domain.com, this way:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.it/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

But, if I try to access http://domain.com/ ( with trailing slash ), mod_rewrite send me to http://www.domain.com// ( with two trailing slashes ).

How to avoid this problem, also?

Comment: Change your pattern to not include the slash in the matched part `^/?(.*)` or change the destination to not add a slash `http://www.domain.com$1`?